# Change the path of package that pip picks up

Tags: pip, virtualenv, vtk

I have multiple versions of a package installed in the system, and need to use pip to install a specific one into a virtual env. By using `pip show <package name>` , I can see that the package is located at `/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7`, if I want to change the path to `usr/lib/bin` how can I do that? I already add the path to `.bashrc`and tried to use add `add2virtualenv`, but they don't seem to work.

Comment: `/usr/lib/bin` looks like a meaningless path. DO you mean `/usr/local/bin`? or just `/usr/bin`? What is you real problem? What Python package do you want to run as a script? May be it already has script(s)?

Answer (score 0):

According to pip documentation at
http://pip.readthedocs.org/en/stable/user_guide/#configuration

You will need to specify the default install location within a pip.ini file, which, also according to the website above is usually located as follows

```
On Unix and Mac OS X the configuration file is: $HOME/.pip/pip.conf

On Windows, the configuration file is: %HOME%\pip\pip.ini
```

The `%HOME%` is located in `C:\Users\username` on windows assuming your name is username

On linux the `$HOME` directory can be located by using `cd ~`

You may have to create the pip.ini file when you find your pip directory. Within your pip.ini or pip.config you will then need to put (assuming your on windows) something like

```
[global]
target=C:\Users\username\Desktop
```

Except that you would replace `C:\Users\username\Desktop` with whatever path you desire. If you are on Linux you would replace it with something like `/usr/local/your/path`

After saving the command would then be

pip install pandas
However, the program you install might assume it will be installed in a certain directory and might not work as a result of being installed elsewhere.